# Getting failed with no key to store while starting Ranger KMS service via ambari

Tags: security, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, mit-kerberos

My cluster is kerberos enabled and I am getting "No key to store" error while starting ranger kms from ambari UI:-

```
**ERROR [/kms] - Exception starting filter authFilter
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No key to store**
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.KerberosAuthenticationHandler.init(KerberosAuthenticationHandler.java:241)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticationHandler.init(DelegationTokenAuthenticationHandler.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.initializeAuthHandler(AuthenticationFilter.java:248)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.initializeAuthHandler(DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.init(AuthenticationFilter.java:234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.init(DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4828)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5508)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No key to store
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.KerberosAuthenticationHandler.init(KerberosAuthenticationHandler.java:225)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No key to store
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.commit(Krb5LoginModule.java:1119)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:588)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.KerberosAuthenticationHandler.init(KerberosAuthenticationHandler.java:222)
        ... 17 more
2016-05-23 09:28:03,330 ERROR StandardContext - Error filterStart
2016-05-23 09:28:03,330 ERROR StandardContext - Context [/kms] startup failed due to previous errors
2016-05-23 09:28:03,332 INFO  KMSWebApp - KMS Stopped
2016-05-23 09:28:03,333 ERROR WebappClassLoader - The web application [/kms] appears to have started a thread named [FileWatchdog] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2016-05-23 09:28:03,334 ERROR WebappClassLoader - The web application [/kms] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2016-05-23 09:28:03,334 ERROR WebappClassLoader - The web application [/kms] appears to have started a thread named [kms.async.multi_dest.batch_kms.async.multi_dest.batch.db_destWriter] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2016-05-23 09:28:03,335 ERROR WebappClassLoader - The web application [/kms] appears to have started a thread named [org.apache.ranger.audit.queue.AuditBatchQueue0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2016-05-23 09:28:03,335 ERROR WebappClassLoader - The web application [/kms] appears to have started a thread named [kms.async.multi_dest.batch_kms.async.multi_dest.batch.hdfs_destWriter] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2016-05-23 09:28:03,335 ERROR WebappClassLoader - The web application [/kms] appears to have started a thread named [org.apache.ranger.audit.queue.AuditBatchQueue1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2016-05-23 09:28:03,336 ERROR WebappClassLoader - The web application [/kms] appears to have started a thread
```

Can someone please help me on this? please let me know if more info required.

Thanks